# Un programa java en neatbean se superponga en un videojuego, que la ventana java se mantenga abierta en un juego

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class Main {
    private static JFrame frame;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Alerta Enemigos");
        frame.setBounds(160, 160, 300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
            

    }


}
```

quisiera que la ventana quedara abierta en un videojuego, agradeceria quienes puedan ayudarme

Comment: No queda muy clara la idea, ¿podrías explicar un poco mas lo que intentas hacer?, la ventana se mantendrá abierta en un juego siempre y cuando no la muevas o la cierres, por como lo muestras parece que intentas hacer un programa Java que se mantenga observando la pantalla y alerte si un x enemigo esta cerca, si es esto tendrías que decirlo, porque no queda muy claro y no podemos dar mejores respuestas o ideas para guiarte.

Comment: No parece una tarea sencilla la que planteas. Una ventana de un programa java totalmente independiente que se mantenga siempre por encima de la ventana de un videojuego aleatorio de tu elección. No te diría que es imposible pero sí que se sale muchísimo del ámbito de este foro

Comment: lo que intento es que la ventana se quede abierta cuando se este ejecutando un juego, para recibir notificaciones desde un servidor, por medio de las teclas se va a ejecutar alguna funciones o seleccionando las opciones de la ventana del programa

Answer (score 1):

De hecho es bastante sencillo poner una ventana encima de todo, todos los JFrames tienen el método [setAlwaysOnTop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)), aunque no todos los sistemas operativos lo soportan (ojo allí).

Solo debes decirle que sí:

```
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

así se ve una ventana cuando está encima auqnue se cambie de proceso:[image: así se ve una ventana cuando está encima aunque se cambie de proceso]

Código de ejemplo hecho en netbeans porque #yolo

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions484980;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Main
     */
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Alerta Enemigos");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(160, 160, 300, 300));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Ahora se complicaría un poco más si tu juego está ya en pantalla completa, pero si ese es el caso me dices y le intento a ver que se puede lograr :3

Comment: si el juego va estar en pantalla completa, si investigue setAlwaysOnTop(true); y de otras formas de poner el programa en primer plano o con un dll para insertar los componentes graficos cuando se ejecuta los graficos del juego.

Comment: voy a porbar todos sus consejos, si no me funciona volvere a preguntar gracias